# How to maintain layout attributes on merged custom android view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-xml

I'm trying to replace a set of views with a custom composite view that is supposed to do exactly the same. Specifically I frequently repeat the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/customLayoutStyle">
  <Button style="@style/customButtonStyle" />
  <TextView style="@style/customTextViewStyle" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My goal is to replace this block by a single `<Highlighter />`.

To this end I define in res/layout/highlighter.xml something like

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@style/customLayoutStyle">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnHighlighter" style="@style/customButtonStyle" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblHighlighter" style="@style/customTextViewStyle" />    
</merge>
```

And in my custom view I have something like

```
public class Highlighter extends LinearLayout {
    public Highlighter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        inflate(context, R.layout.highlighter, this);
    }
}
```

This mostly works, but it seems some of the layout parameters of the `<merge>` tag are ignored. This [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/snc5nrixxmn4igs/2013-02-09%2012.20.24.png) illustrates what seems to be wrong. The 3 images on the bottom row are aligned correctly, using 3x the LinearLayout block I'm trying to replace. Only the top-left image uses the custom view. My guess is that the layout parameters for padding and layout_weight are lost. Am I doing something wrong, or do I need a workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right about the parameters being lost. To workaround this you can put the style definition for Highlighter in the layout where you define the Highlighter.

E.g.

```
<yournamespace.Highlighter 
    style="@style/customLayoutStyle"
/>
```

Comment: That's what I went with eventually. Thanks.

Comment: This is not very satisfactory for me because I need to repeat those everywhere my custom view is needed, even if they are intrinsic to my custom view. I guess there is no other choice than to set them manually in my custom view constructor

Answer (score 2):

Years later this is still something that's complicated on Android, but it can be done.

You can do it by using style attribute in your custom view, then setting the style in you theme.

Don't set the style in `res/layout/highlighter.xml`:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <Button android:id="@+id/btnHighlighter" style="@style/customButtonStyle" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lblHighlighter" style="@style/customTextViewStyle" />    
</merge>
```

Then in your custom view:

```
public class Highlighter extends LinearLayout {
    public Highlighter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        // The third constructor parameter is you friend
        super(context, attrs, R.attr.highlighterStyle);
        inflate(context, R.layout.highlighter, this);
    }
}
```

Define the attribute in `values/attrs_highlighter_view.xml`:

```
<resources>
    <attr name="highlighterStyle" format="reference" />
</resources>
```

Now you can set the style in your theme

```
<style name="YourAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="preferenceViewStyle">@style/customLayoutStyle</item>
</style>
```

This way this style will be used by default whenever you use `Highlighter`.

Usage of your custom view is then like you want:

```
<com.your.app.Highlighter
    android:id="@+id/highlighter"
    ... />
```

I have not verified if this works with `layout_weight`, but it does work with `padding`, `background` etc.

Comment: I have been looking for this for a long time.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on [muscardinus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61103253), starting from API 21 (Lollipop), `View`s accept a `defStyleRes` as fourth constructor argument, so you can skip the `attr` part and just do:

In styles.xml

```xml
<style name="CustomView">
    // Define your style here
</style>
```

CustomView.kt

```kt
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0,
) : LinearLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, R.style.CustomView) {

    ...

}
```

Note that you need at least `minSdkVersion 21` for this.